# Стрельба в Unity по направлении курсора + Flip

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите, пожайлуйста.
Проблема заключается в том, что когда персонаж смотрит вправо - всё хорошо и стрельба правильная и оружие правильно следит за курсором(ДУЛО ИДЕТ ЗА КУРСОРОМ), но когда повернуть персонажа влево (приклад идет за курсором).
Оружие при этом смотрит влево( Flip выполнен).
Оружие так же пробовал поворачивать отдельно ( не через дочерний объект персонажа).

Не могу понять в чем проблема из-за того, что Atan2 при изменении scale на минус?
Нужно чтобы при повороте дула так и поворачивалось за курсором.
Скрипт нарисан по видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDVMkJkNq88&t=194s

Спасибо!

```
public class Kalashnikov : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject gunPosition;
    [SerializeField] GameObject bullet;
    public float offset;
    public Transform shotDirection;
    public PlayerMover playerMover;
    private float _shotTime;
    public float startTime;
    float rotateZ;


    Vector3 checkScale;

    
    void Update()
    {

        if(_shotTime<=0)
        { 
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                Instantiate(bullet, shotDirection.position,transform.rotation);
                _shotTime = startTime;

                }
        }
        else
        {
            _shotTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CheckScale();
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;

       rotateZ =  Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * (Mathf.Rad2Deg);

        transform.position = gunPosition.transform.position;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotateZ + offset);

      

    }
   
    void CheckScale()
    {
         checkScale = transform.localScale;
        if (playerMover.isFacingLeft == false)
        {
            
            checkScale.x = 1f;
        
            transform.localScale = checkScale;
        }

        if (playerMover.isFacingLeft == true)
        {
            
            checkScale.x = -1f;
           
            transform.localScale = checkScale;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ, нужно сделать отдельный поворот оружия(не через дочерний от персонажа). И сделать поворот по оси(у).

```
 void CheckScale()
    {
         checkScale = transform.localScale;
        if (playerMover.isFacingLeft == false)
        {
            
           checkScale.y = 1f;
        
            transform.localScale = checkScale;
        }

        if (playerMover.isFacingLeft == true)
        {
            
            checkScale.y = -1f;

            transform.localScale = checkScale;
        }
    }
```